# devexpress grindcontrol custom summary only selected rows

Tags: devexpress, summary, gridcontrol

I have a grouped grid control with group sum, summarytype: custom. I would like to have the follwoing: if the user selects or deselects a row, the corresponding group summary changes too. I need also only the sum of the selected rows.

I have this code:

```
Private Sub gvUtalhatok_CustomSummaryCalculate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs) Handles gvUtalhatok.CustomSummaryCalculate
        Dim View As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
        If e.SummaryProcess = CustomSummaryProcess.Start Then custom_sum = 0
        If e.SummaryProcess = CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate Then
            For i = 0 To View.GetSelectedRows.Count - 1
                custom_sum += Convert.ToDecimal(View.GetRowCellValue(View.GetSelectedRows(i), "BRUTTO"))
            Next
            'custom_sum += Convert.ToDecimal(e.FieldValue)
        End If
        If e.SummaryProcess = CustomSummaryProcess.Finalize Then e.TotalValue = custom_sum
End Sub
```

And this:

```
Private Sub gvUtalhatok_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Data.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles gvUtalhatok.SelectionChanged
        gvUtalhatok.UpdateGroupSummary()
End Sub
```

The problem is, that if I select a row, I get three times the sum of the column and all group row show the same sum value.

How do I modify the code to show correct sum values and only for the group row, in wich the rows are selected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should remove the loop from CustomSummaryCalculate event handler.  Instead, use the following code:

```
Private Sub gvUtalhatok_CustomSummaryCalculate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Data.CustomSummaryEventArgs) Handles gvUtalhatok.CustomSummaryCalculate
        Dim View As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
        If e.SummaryProcess = CustomSummaryProcess.Start Then custom_sum = 0
        If e.SummaryProcess = CustomSummaryProcess.Calculate Then
           if View.IsRowSelected(e.RowHandle) then
                        e.TotalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(e.TotalValue) + 
Convert.ToDecimal(View.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "BRUTTO"))
           End If
        End If
End Sub
```